# my istio-ingressgateway pod does come up when instaling Kubeflow from the kubeflow/manifest (istio 1.17)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, kubeflow

I will be glad if someoone kindly help me with this please. I am a newbie in DEVOPS.
I have installed a standalone cluster of kubernetes using kubectl 1.27.4 and minikube version: v1.31.1 on ubuntu 22.04.
I want to run kubeflow using [kubeflow manifest](https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests/tree/master). My minikube is launched with no drivers and all the addons are disabled.
`minikube start --driver=none \ --kubernetes-version=v1.27.4 \ --extra-config=apiserver.service-account-signing-key-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/sa.key \ --extra-config=apiserver.service-account-issuer=kubernetes.default.svc  --extra-config=kubelet.resolv-conf=/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`

I then start installing the kubeflow using this [tutorial](https://mlops-for-all.github.io/en/docs/setup-components/install-components-kf). I have tried both the version on the tutorial, version 1.7 and i have also clone the master branch.

when i run `kustomize build common/istio-1-16/istio-install/base | kubectl apply -f -` or `kustomize build common/istio-1-17/istio-install/base | kubectl apply -f -`
Just one pod comes up and the other shows running both never comes up

```
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
istio-ingressgateway-79b665c95-xm454   0/1     Running   0          16s
istiod-86457659bb-5h58w                1/1     Running   0          16s
```

I have check the logs of the pod
`kubectl logs istio-ingressgateway-79b665c95-xm454 -n istio-system`
and the output looks like this

```
warn    sds failed to warm certificate: failed to generate workload certificate: create certificate: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup istiod.istio-system.svc on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.212:33211->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
```

I used the this kubernetes debugging [proposals](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/)
when i run `kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes.default` the nslookup command fails with the following output
`;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

command terminated with exit code 1
`
and from the document it says errors as such shows that there is a problem with the coreDNS or kube-dns.

I check the coreDNS `kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns` and the found the following error

`[INFO] 127.0.0.1:51197 - 25941 "HINFO IN 6443204498907807806.1822223731783212999. udp 57 false 512" - - 0 2.000526828s [ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 6443204498907807806.1822223731783212999. HINFO: read udp 10.244.0.227:60893->195.130.130.4:53: i/o timeout [INFO] 127.0.0.1:44564 - 55305 "HINFO IN 6443204498907807806.1822223731783212999. udp 57 false 512" - - 0 2.000507048s [ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 6443204498907807806.1822223731783212999. HINFO: read udp 10.244.0.227:58119->195.130.131.4:53: i/o timeout`

I have check my coreDNS configMap and it looks like this

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        log
        errors
        health {
           lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        hosts {
           127.0.0.1 host.minikube.internal
           fallthrough
        }
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
           max_concurrent 1000
        }
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }

kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-08-13T13:49:27Z"
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "273280"
  uid: 93c25cc7-7d49-4ab3-8c12-f466d55df1b6
```

Since the I used `--extra-config=kubelet.resolv-conf=/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`, I have also tried replacing /etc/resolv.conf with /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf.

I have tried also tried using the nameserver Ip in the /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf as shown below

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        log
        errors
        health {
           lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        hosts {
           127.0.0.1 host.minikube.internal
           fallthrough
        }
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
           max_concurrent 1000
        }
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
    cluster.local:53 {
        forward . 195.130.131.4
        cache 30
        errors
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-08-13T13:49:27Z"
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "273280"
  uid: 93c25cc7-7d49-4ab3-8c12-f466d55df1b6
```

Comment: are there any errors in istiod pod logs

Comment: i found this when i describe the istio-ingress pod 'Warning  FailedMount  111s (x3 over 113s)  kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "istiod-ca-cert" : configmap "istio-ca-root-cert" not found'   and when i describe the istio od i got this    'Warning  Unhealthy  8m11s  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503'

Comment: when i chech the logs of the istio-ingres pod i get this  'warn sds failed to warm certificate: failed to generate workload certificate: create certificate: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup istiod.istio-system.svc on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.254:46977->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout'